# react-native android build fails with execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. , but iOS works

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I've configured my office laptop to get the project running. I followed the same approach as another new joiner setup his laptop and his project is working. But mine is not. I used the proper sdk version which is required 31.

Can't figure out the issue. I tried cleaning up Android Studio with all the sdk stuff and reinstalling it. Still having this issue when trying to `Configure project :react-native-reanimated` . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: here's the error]

[image: sdk manager]

[image: sdk tools]

EDIT :

I'm using Mac M1 Pro. I thought I don't need to install rosetta.But after some investigation, found out that I need rosetta. So I installed rosetta and got this working

Comment: Share build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in error message:

"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0"

Fix it upgrading your gradble and checking your project before run.

Answer (score 0):

for react-native-reanimated you need to add
Add Reanimated's Babel plugin to your `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ...
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
```

or you need to follow step from this link
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation

hope it's working fine